# Where can I find graph.dll for graphviz?

Tags: c++, graphviz

I want to use graphviz as a library. In project settings I've added

> "C:\Program Files x86\Graphviz2.38\include"

into the `Include directories` and

> "C:\Program Files x86\Graphviz2.38\lib\release\lib"

into the `Library directories` and added all `.lib` files into project.

I compile the project but it can't run the program because it can't find `graph.dll` file. I can't find this file on my PC at all. What am I missing?

My code copied from graphviz tutorial:

```
#include <graphviz\gvc.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GVC_t *gvc;
    Agraph_t *g;
    FILE *fp;
    gvc = gvContext();
    fp = fopen("graph.dot", "r");
    g = agread(fp, 0);
    gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot");
    gvRender(gvc, g, "plain", stdout);
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
    agclose(g);
    return (gvFreeContext(gvc));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question, the current version is 2.38. Per [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/540947/98223), 2.28 is the last version with graph.dll. I haven't found why it was removed or how user code is supposed to change in response.

2.28 is available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hdashuttle/files/Tools/) (for now), and I've confirmed that it comes with graph.dll.